# Making all the image black except of some white objects

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm using `Adobe Photoshop CC`, where I have coloured some objects with `white`, and want to set all the remaining part of the image to `black`.

I have used the `Paint Bucket Tool`, but since the objects that I coloured are `ellipses`, when I use that tool, I find that the ellipses start to have **irregular** shapes as I'm colouring with `black` using the tool.

What would be a better way to that?

Thanks.

Comment: This is the issue. Your object need to be at separate layers. In this case you can change background with easier. Otherwise try you use magic wand or other selection tool to select exact area for recolor. Photoshop has layered structure. When you edit objects at one layer, the rest layers and objects are protected from your edit. I afraid you need to read a bit about basics of Photoshop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey there so as @Simplicity mentioned, Photoshop works in layers and this is some of the fundamentals of the program.

I wanted to clarify the answer though for people in future.

Firstly [here](http://helpx.adobe.com/en/photoshop/using/layer-basics.html) are some pointers on layer basics which is a good place if you are just starting.

Secondly in this particular example the problem is that the OP is experiencing some issues because the black fill using the [paint bucket tool](http://helpx.adobe.com/en/photoshop/using/filling-stroking-selections-layers-paths.html) (G) is not aligning smoothly with the edges of the white ellipse. This is an ideal example as to why layers should be used in Photoshop.

To over come this problem you simply use a layer that is entirely black placed beneath a layer that is transparent except for the white ellipses.

[image: Layers Panel]

Here you can see the arrangement of the layers and the effect that it has on the ellipses. As you can see there is a smooth edge because the black fill actually continues beneath the white ellipse so there are no pixels left blank. Arrow 1 is pointing at the icon used to make a new layer, alternatively you can navigate to Layer > New > Layer or use the shortcut SHIFT + CTRL + N

Happy Photoshopping!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your nice answer. What I was looking for!